# Showing a basis exists for a particular transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be $n$-dimensional vector space over reals. $T: V \to V $ linear of rank $r < n$ , $T^2 = T$. Show $V$ has a basis ${v_1...v_n}$ s.t $T(v_i) =v_i$ for $i=1...r, 0$ otherwise.

Could someone point to me what exactly im trying to show here? Im used to showing something is a basis by seeing its a linearly independent spanning set. I guess im not quite sure how the transformation comes into play into this proof, though I believe i perfectly well understand how this transformation works on said basis.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that

- The eigenvalues of $T$ are in $\{0,1\}$
- We can select a basis of $V$ consisting entirely of eigenvectors of $T$.  That is, we need to show that $T$ is diagonalizable.

Suppose that $v_1, \dots, v_r$ are linearly independent eigenvectors associated with $1$, and that $v_{r+1},\dots,v_n$ are linearly independent eigenvectors associated with $0$.  Then $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is necessarily a basis of $V$ satisfying the necessary conditions.

Comment: I understand that this projection transformation works as you propose, but what im missing is how I know that such a basis exists? it seems obvious to me that if it exists...this is the one it should be.

Comment: @MSEoris how do you know that $T$ is diagonalizable?  What methods do you have for showing that some transformation is diagonalizable?  Have you encountered minimal polynomials?

Comment: Diagonalizable transformations are precisely those that have a basis consisting of eigenvectors

Comment: I dont know of minimal polynomials but am interested in how they help show that the transformation is diagnolizable. In short, I know very little about testing if a matrix is diagnolizable

Comment: @MSEoris if you were assigned this problem, I'm wondering how you were expected to solve it... do you know anything about Jordan Canonical form?

Comment: Its a problem I encountered while studying for a qualifying exam, Its possible the question is outside of the scope of what Ive learned so far. I know of Jordan Form but have never used it.

Comment: @MSEoris this problem is most easily solved using Jordan form, in one way or another.  The gist is as follows: 
$T^2 - T = 0$.  So,
if $J$ is the Jordan form of $T$, then $J^2 - J = J(J-I) = 0$.
This necessarily implies that the blocks of $J$ have length $1$ (i.e. $J$ is diagonal).  So, $T$ is diagonalizable, since it is similar to $J$, whihch is diagonal.

Answer (score 4):

In fact $T$ is a projection and we can prove easily that

$$V=\underbrace{\ker (I-T)}_{=\operatorname{im T}}\oplus \ker T$$
so take a basis adapted  to this decomposition *(and notice that if $v\in\operatorname{im T}$ then T(v)=v)*  and you have the desired result.